# Existence of Cartan involution

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

From the wikipedia article on Cartan decompositions, a Cartan involution of a real semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with Killing form $B:\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Lie algebra involution $\theta:\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ so that $(X,Y):=-B(X,\theta(Y))$ is an inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$.

It is claimed that every real semisimple Lie group has a Cartan involution, and that it is unique up to an inner automorphism.

I am looking for a proof of this claim.

Comment: Have you looked at any source beyond the Wikipedia article? I am relatively sure there are many textbooks and lecture notes out there which contain proofs of this.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I searched for it in some textbooks and on the internet, this claim seems to be assumed without proof in a lot of places. Are there specific sources you have in mind?

Comment: 2.27-2.31 of https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~cap/files/wisser.pdf. Theorem B in 2.10 of https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/Samelson-LieAlg.pdf.